# Default Applications reset to their default settings after a reboot Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: default, default-programs, dconf

So I have this issue where the Default Applications, reset to the default state upon rebooting the system.

```
Web: Google Chrome changes back to Firefox
Mail: Mailspring -> Thunderbird
Video: VLC -> Videos
```

I went through my `dconf` settings to see if something bombs out there or at least overwrites, but couldn't find anything.

1. Is there some options or a config I an check to prevent this from happening?
2. If not, is there a way I can automate to change the default programs, some command I can script out to run on the startup?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Try my answer. If it doesn't help, create a new user account, called "Guest", or whatever, log in there, and see if the same problem occurs there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings/Default Applications**...

[image]

**Update #1:**

Created a "Guest" account, and the problem does not occur there. The problem is local to your own account. Probably something wrong in ~/.cache or ~/.local or ~/.config folders.

Comment: These are the settings that keep changing upon restarting the system and every time I need to manually change them back to what I want them to be. 
I wouldn't mind that behavior if I could change these myself via command

Comment: @MaTi Did you create the "Guest" account?

Comment: it doesn't happen on the other account

Comment: @MaTi Then the problem is local to your own account. Probably something wrong in ~/.cache or ~/.local or ~/.config folders.

Comment: @MaTi Status please...